# Error while doing mina setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, deployment

I am using mina to deploy my rails app. I am using aws with nginx and rvm.

Whenever I do `mina setup` I get

```
    Permission denied (publickey).

 !     Command failed.
       Failed with status 1 (255)
```

Here is my `deploy.rb` file

```
require 'mina/bundler'
require 'mina/rails'
require 'mina/git'
# require 'mina/rbenv'  # for rbenv support. (http://rbenv.org)
require 'mina/rvm'    # for rvm support. (http://rvm.io)

# Basic settings:
#   domain       - The hostname to SSH to.
#   deploy_to    - Path to deploy into.
#   repository   - Git repo to clone from. (needed by mina/git)
#   branch       - Branch name to deploy. (needed by mina/git)
set :user, 'ubuntu'
set :domain, 'domain.com'
set :deploy_to, '/usr/share/nginx/html/project'
set :repository, 'https://mc_cannibal@bitbucket.org/mc_cannibal/fuitter2.git'
set :branch, 'master'
# set :forward_agent, true

# For system-wide RVM install.
#   set :rvm_path, '/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm'

# Manually create these paths in shared/ (eg: shared/config/database.yml) in your server.
# They will be linked in the 'deploy:link_shared_paths' step.
set :shared_paths, ['config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'log']

# Optional settings:
#   set :user, 'foobar'    # Username in the server to SSH to.
#   set :port, '30000'     # SSH port number.
#   set :forward_agent, true     # SSH forward_agent.

# This task is the environment that is loaded for most commands, such as
# `mina deploy` or `mina rake`.
task :environment do
  # If you're using rbenv, use this to load the rbenv environment.
  # Be sure to commit your .ruby-version or .rbenv-version to your repository.
  # invoke :'rbenv:load'

  # For those using RVM, use this to load an RVM version@gemset.
  invoke :'rvm:use[ruby-1.9.3-p125@default]'
end

# Put any custom mkdir's in here for when `mina setup` is ran.
# For Rails apps, we'll make some of the shared paths that are shared between
# all releases.
task :setup => :environment do
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]

  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"]
  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml"]
  queue  %[echo "-----> Be sure to edit '#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/database.yml' and 'secrets.yml'."]

  queue %[
    repo_host=`echo $repo | sed -e 's/.*@//g' -e 's/:.*//g'` &&
    repo_port=`echo $repo | grep -o ':[0-9]*' | sed -e 's/://g'` &&
    if [ -z "${repo_port}" ]; then repo_port=22; fi &&
    ssh-keyscan -p $repo_port -H $repo_host >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  ]
end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy => :environment do
  to :before_hook do
    # Put things to run locally before ssh
  end
  deploy do
    # Put things that will set up an empty directory into a fully set-up
    # instance of your project.
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

    to :launch do
      queue "mkdir -p #{deploy_to}/#{current_path}/tmp/"
      queue "touch #{deploy_to}/#{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
    end
  end
end

# For help in making your deploy script, see the Mina documentation:
#
#  - http://nadarei.co/mina
#  - http://nadarei.co/mina/tasks
#  - http://nadarei.co/mina/settings
#  - http://nadarei.co/mina/helpers
```

Comment: can you ssh to your aws instance without password?

Comment: @LongNguyen yes I can. I have downloaded a .pem file then I would `ssh -i "fuitter.pem" ubuntu@52.88.43.104`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have provided that you currently ssh to your instance using `.pem` file and as Mina doesn't provide a way to connect to ssh using `.pem` file (yet). So you can add your public_key of your computer to your instance and enable login via public key, which means you can ssh to your instance without password or `.pem` file.

To copy your public key to your ec2 instance (for Linux or Mac only):

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -i "fuitter.pem" ubuntu@52.88.43.104 "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

ssh to your ec2 instance and restart ssh service:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Then try to ssh to your instance without pem file

```
ssh ubuntu@52.88.43.104
```

If it works, mina will connect to your instance successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As [Long Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5572893/long-nguyen) stated [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33929001/14043328), Mina doesn't provide a way to connect to ssh using .pem file (yet). So, we need to add the public_key of our computer to the instance and enable login via public key. That's to say connecting to the instance without a password.

However, I have faced some errors with his steps, so here are mine:

- Generate an SSH key: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM`
- Check it using: `ls -lah ~/.ssh`, the output should have `id_rsa.pub id_rsa`
- Add it to the `authorized_keys` in your instance:
  `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | sudo ssh -i ~/Downloads/my_key.pem ubuntu@x.xxx.xx.xxx "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`
- Check whether ssh-ing is permitted by the instance, in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, check that `PasswordAuthentication` is  `yes` and is not commented. (This should be run on the instance itself)
- Restart sshd service if you make any changes to this file:
  `service ssh restart # On Ubuntu` or  `service sshd restart # On Centos`
- You can now connect to your instance without anu password like thisL: `ssh ubuntu@EC2-Public-IP`
- If you needed to set a passowrd for the instance upon loging, try: `sudo passwd ubuntu`